# How to take a house apart in sections to move?

Tags: old-house, relocating

I live in NC and looking for a free house to move and relocate. First, does anyone know of or how to find one within reasonable distance and second, is it possible to move one in smaller sections without doing a complete dismantle? Any help on finding and moving one is sincerely appreciated. Thanks to all. Randy

Comment: without more context it sounds like you are neck deep in an XY problem.

Comment: A Mobile (prefabricated) home is designed to be moved. Most other homes are too expensive to move unless there is a strong motivation to save them because they are historical.

Comment: freecycle? craigslist?

Usually a chainsaw is used to cut the house after bracing any structure that will need support during transport.

The sections are then jacked up and loaded onto semi-trailers.

Are you planning on doing this yourself?

Comment: In all the house moves I've seen, it's going to cost you close to the price of a new home to shift an existing building. The equipment and required skills are fairly specialized and very pricey. Not to mention the cost of the police escorts, power company/telephone company to raise overhead lines, permits to have roads closed... You can do it, but it's not something you'll do lightly or cheaply.

Comment: I agree with @ring, we did not have police escorts but roads were blocked off and overhead utility’s moved (more expensive than the move permit). The crawlers only move at ~3 miles per hour quite expensive.+

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about home improvement but about home relocation.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a shopping question and would be off topic. So I will discuss moving.
I have been involved in moving 3 houses. None were on a slab. All 3 were jacked up and moved in major pieces. Porches removed , all the electrical had to be brought up to code. Note all 3 were Victorians that were constructed well beyond anything in the last 50 years. Taking a house down in pieces would take more disassembly time and repair than it would be worth, unless you found an old sears mail order home That was in good shape (don’t laugh they are out there) these small homes were prefabricated and could possibly be dismantled and reassembled within reason. Other than that a stick built house is not really feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Moving houses is a **very expensive** proposition. Unless it's next door (and perhaps even then) you'll pay more to move the old one than it would cost to build a better new one. Place I used to work was offered one, for free, less than 1/4 mile (500 meters) down the street. Cost to move it was going to be on the order of 1/4 million dollars. They passed. It got torn down (nobody else could afford to move it, either.)

Seems like a nice idea to reuse one, but unless you have gobs of money to waste, it's not practical, nearly always.